# Java window won't update without re-sizing the the application window

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, repaint

I'm trying to make the integer near "time left" to decrements by one and repaint every second **but I can only see the changes when I resize the window constantly**. I've tried this in Jcreator 3 in windows and in Ububtu 11.10 command line but it still doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

class StatusPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    int time = 60;
    int round = 1;
    Timer timer;

    public StatusPanel() {
        this.timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        this.timer.start();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    public void updateTime() {
        if (time > 0) {
            time--;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics page) {

        super.paint(page);

        page.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        String sTime = String.valueOf(time);
        String sRound = String.valueOf(round);


        page.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        page.drawString(sTime, 253, 149);
        page.drawString(sRound, 230, 105);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        this.updateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: call `repaint` from `updateTime`

Comment: Yesss!!!!! thank you. You must've guessed it already, I'm a still noob at java. Again, thank you! :)

Comment: Frankly, I'm surprised I didn't find a duplicate question. Anyways, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768619/paint-and-repaint-in-java?rq=1

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void updateTime(){
    if (time>0) time--;
}
```

When `time` is changed, your component should be redrawn. However, Swing normally thinks of components as static objects, and doesn't redraw them continuously. You need to tell Swing that you want your component repainted:

```
public void updateTime(){
    if (time>0){
        time--;
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

On a side note, perhaps you should stop your timer when you reach zero. It seems no longer used.