# JPanel's paintComponent();

Tags: java, swing

Here is a code sample:

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel
{
      Image img;
      public MyClass(Image img) {
      this.img = img;
      }
      ...

      void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
      }

      void someFunction() {
           img = (Image) inputStream.getObject();
      }
}
```

Will the `paintComponent()` will also get automatically called if `img` so much as receives a brand new `Image` instance?

Also, is there any use to the `paint()`and `repaint()`methods in this context?

Comment: No, Swing will not repaint if you assign a variable a new value. I recommend checking out [custom painting in swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). In `someFunction` you should call `repaint`

Comment: Remember that the first line of code in an overridden paintComponent method *must* be `super.paintComponent(g)`.  Otherwise, you will get unpredictable painting artifacts.

Comment: Thank you. I infer that `repaint()` calls `paintComponent()`internally, is that right? @VGR: Would you mind explaing why is it so? Like, what does the superclass' `paintComponent()`do specifically and where would those artifacts come from?

Comment: Yes, `repaint()` will go through the steps of repainting the component and will eventually get to `paintComponent()` and draw the image, make sure you call `repaint()` every time you update the data behind the rendering, so the rendering matches the data

Comment: Oracle's [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and the Java tutorial's [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) explain it better than I can.  At the very least, it is needed to ensure the background is properly painted.  I believe it performs some painting optimizations as well, at least on some platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In particular changing a `Component`'s variables or calling methods like `someFunction()` does not implicitly run `paintComponent()` unless the method is design to do that. For instance the `someFunction()` method can be made to repaint whenever it's called as follows:

```
void someFunction() {
   img = (Image) inputStream.getObject();
   repaint();
}
```

But you'd still have to call `repaint()` wherever you change `img`, which will be prone to bugs if you do it alot. A smoother approach (which allows you passes in images externally if you might do that) is to write a setter that suggest a repaint.

```
public void setImage(Image img){
   this.img = img;
   repaint();
}
```

and use use this method instead of changing the variable directly. e.g.:

```
void someFunction() {
   setImage((Image) inputStream.getObject());
}
```

Finally, `repaint()` may ultimately invoke `paint()` but you generally do not call `paint()` directly because `repaint()` is better managed. See [paint vs repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768619/paint-and-repaint-in-java) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more information.