# Why do we use repaint() method only in Itemlistener, not in Actionlistener

Tags: java, awt

I am starting Java and found this interesting.

In Java AWT when we create a button then we use an ActionListener and then we write a `paint()` function.

But when we create a checkbox then we use an ItemListener and in the `paint()` function we use `repaint()` and then we write `repaint()`. Why do we use `repaint()`? Why do we not use `repaint()` in case of an ActionListener?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768619/paint-and-repaint-in-java

Comment: Yes, I read this. My specific question is why we use only in Itemlistener not in Actionlistener.

Comment: "public void repaint()
Repaints this component.
If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible." javadoc. You should understand first what they do, and you will be able to use them properly.

Comment: Thanks eldo. I will do some more practice to understand better. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Who is that “we” that does the things you describe? There is no such rule regarding listeners and `paint()`/`repaint()` methods. If you are referring to a particular code, provide the reference.