# How to ensure that a JTextField input meets requirements?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So I'm making a module that has three JTextField windows corresponding for 24 bit RGB color values "R", "G" and "B" with buttons for decrement/increment. The module is supposed to take these values and display the color. I did that and it works, but I need to ensure some details about the inputs and I don't know how to. These details are:

1. if you enter a value outside of 0 and 255 it will be treated as 0
2. if you click a decrement button when the value is 0 it won't drop it to -1
3. if you click an increment button when the value is 255 it won't rise to 256. I have no idea how to do it. I tried to google it but 
   I can't find what I need. I'd appreciate some guidance

EDIT:
I tried to add some if statements to the ActionPerformed method but all it does is returns a whole bunch of errors when I run the module and try the value out of range

EDIT2: for example, I had this but it doesn't work :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String r,g,b;

    if (e.getSource() == tf1) {
        r = tf1.getText();
        this.r =Integer.parseInt(r);
        if (this.r < 0 && this.r > 255)
            this.r =0;
        color(); }
```

I have nothing for my buttons because I have completely no idea how to

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did you find difficult? Where are you stuch? Show your effort and the code you have so far, please

Comment: I tried to do it with the if statements but it doesn't work. In general I have no idea how to solve it and where to start? I'm not looking for a solution just a guidance what I can use to make it work. I'll figure out the rest on my own

Comment: Show us your attemtps then. Please, however, try to stay as close to [mcve] as possible. Carefully read what it is and apply that logic to make your example easy to be helped with

Comment: @zueyl Why do you not use a JSpinner since you want a number input field with up/down buttons? No need to work with a JTextField for this problem.

Comment: I edited my post with the code I had initially for it that didn't work

Comment: @Progman it's a college assignment so it has been specified for us

Comment: Your code is checking if r > 255 **AND** r < 0. A number cannot be greater than 255 and less than 0 so this statement will always return false. Did you mean **OR**?

Comment: @Wrokar yes you're right, but it still throws the same errors in the console

Comment: @zueyl what is the error you're getting? Without knowing the exact error you're seeing in the console it's hard to go further.

Comment: *"I edited my post with the code"* So .. when will we see the MCVE suggested by @Fureeish. (In case you're confused, uncompilable code snippets != MCVE.)

Comment: BTW - while the spinners suggested by @Progman are a good idea, I'd use a `JColorChooser` for this type of problem.

Comment: Probably you need `repaint` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768619/paint-and-repaint-in-java

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you might need some data validation from your input sources. We can't see your code, but one way to validate would be have your getters/setters generated for your variables. (Depending on the editor you have, these can be generated rather quickly). Within the values setter - you should be able to do some data validation.

If you post some code, you might get more meaningful feedback.

More on getters and setters in Java: https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices

EDIT:
Now that you've posted code. Change the && to || and that should take care of your issue.

It is still better to data validate this with a getter/setter.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Answered it with what details were provided at the time. Has been updated now to include the solution.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: We lack crucial information about the problem. Providing answers to inompletely described problems is not encouraged

Comment: Okay - sounds like a plan.